Firebase console hangs on cloud messaging tab
I used Firebase cloud messaging before in another project with no issues, on this new project i am facing a strange behavior where the the firebase console essentially hangs in the project settings / cloud messaging tab
see attached image


If you're having a problem with the Firebase console, contact Firebase support directly.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Any relevant messages in the developer/JavaScript console of your browser?

firebaser here
There's indeed a confirmed problem right now with permissions in the Firebase console affecting Cloud Messaging. The engineering team is working on a rollback or a fix. We just posted it to our status dashboard, and I recommend tracking there for updates.

Oh good, I am not the only one.
Nothing to do with us, probably some service disruptions on their side.
My guess is 'app distribution'
https://status.firebase.google.com/
Service disruption
